# Menu of Shape selection in main( )

Tags: java

This is what I have so far:

```
package weiss.util;
import java.util.*;
import weiss.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class practiceSort
{
    public static void main( )
    {
        boolean done;
        String oneLine;
        done = false;

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in) );

    while (!done)
    {
        System.out.println( "Circle, Rectangle, Square, Trapezoid, Octagon, Equilateral Triangle: ");

        oneLine = in.readLine( );
        if( oneLine != null )
        {

        }   
        else
        {
            done = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write my `main( )` method to allow the user to select from a menu of Shapes that I have already created subclasses for in other classes. It needs to ask for and get the information specific to the Shape subclass being created. The actual input of the values for the dimensions of the shapes is done in the application class( ie. `main()` ). It needs to allow the user to select more than one Shape if desired, and then sort either all the Shapes based either on area or perimeter and also sort the same way but only compare similar shapes based on area or perimeter. The user must be able to choose either option.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance for any advice/coding help that could benefit my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking the user to choose a shape in the main menu, you may want to give a table with numbers corresponding to each shape.  That way you can have them enter a integer, read that integer, and determine which method to call by using a switch statement.

Example menu:

1. Circle
2. Rectangle
3. Square
4. Trapezoid

Please select a shape:

So if they select 1, case 1: of the switch statement will call getCircleData() which would ask the user for the circle information, then you can display an output of whatever you're planning and using the data for.

Not sure if this was of any help, but I thought it might point in you in the right direction.